# Flask -Test TemplateNot found exception

Tags: python, flask, nosetests, flask-testing

I want to test some routes but when i run nosetests it writes error

> "TemplateNotFound: main.html"

I have `render_templates = False` in my flask test Class.

For example i want to test this endpoint

```
  @users.route('/test', methods=['GET','POST'])
  def test():
    return render_template('main.html')
```

I made test.py file with this **`TestCase`**

```
class TestConfig(object):
   DEBUG = False
   TESTING = True
   WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = False
   PRESERVE_CONTEXT_ON_EXCEPTION = False
   SECRET_KEY = "sekret_key"
   template_folder = "/home/project_name/templates"

class TestNotRenderTemplates(TestCase):

  render_templates = False

  def create_app(self):
     app = Flask(__name__)
     app = create_app(TestConfig)
     return app


  def test_assert_mytemplate_used(self):
     response = self.client.get("/u/test")
     self.assert_template_used('main.html')
```

Comment: The method `test_assert_mytemplate_used` should be inside the class, unless it is a formatting error.

Comment: Where have you placed the template file? you seem to have a variable 'template_folder', but you do not seem to use it explicitly.

Comment: Yes it's inside the class  ..

Comment: @Vilsepi  this main.html file is located in "/home/project_name/templates/main.html"